# Modx Easy 2 Galley doesn't create images in thumbnail

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

It looks strange, but when I synchronize my gallery all little images from folder '_thumbnails' are deleted and not created again. But big images exist in folder 'gallery'.

chmod 0777 gallery/_thumbnail - didn't help

My version of Modx is evolution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked ownership? I've had problems with the same thing in the past. Make sure the ownership of the gallery/ (recursive) is apache or higher.